# difference between find . –name *.txt and find . –name "*.txt"

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find

I want to know what is the difference between this two commands..

```
find . –name *.txt

find . –name "*.txt"
```

I run it in the system and cant find any difference,
what does the sign `" "` do?

Comment: Aside: it looks like you have used a word processor to prepare this question. Never use a word processor to edit code, unless you like hunting for invisible characters and characters that look like ASCII but are not.

Answer (score 8):

When you don't use quotes around the glob pattern, i.e. when you say:

```
find . -name *.txt
```

then the shell would expand `*.txt` to the matching files in the *current directory* before passing those as an argument to `find`.  If no file matching the pattern is found, then the behaviour is similar to the quoted variant.

When you use quotes, i.e. when you say:

```
find . -name "*.txt"
```

the shell passes `*.txt` as an argument to `find`.

**Always use quotes when specifying a glob** (esp. when used as an argument to `find`).

---

An example might help:

```
$ touch {1..5}.txt                # Create a few .txt files
$ ls
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt  5.txt
$ find . -name *.txt              # find *.txt files
find: paths must precede expression: 2.txt
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
$ find . -name "*.txt"            # find "*.txt" files
./2.txt
./4.txt
./3.txt
./5.txt
./1.txt
```